# Topology generated by basis equals intersection of all topologies that contain A

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Here is my proof I was wondering any critiques to my proof.

If A is a basis;The topology generated by A equals collections of all unions of elements of A that is 
$\tau = \bigcup_{i \in I: B_i \in A}\ \{B_i\}$
Consider also $L = \bigcap_{q \in Q: \ A \  \subset \  \tau_q} \ \tau_q$.

Since A is a basis, so we have $A \subset \tau$, so there exists $q \in Q$ such that $\tau_q = \tau$, therefore $L \subset \tau$.

Since B_i is open set in $\tau_q \forall \ q \in Q$, so $\forall \ q \in Q $ we have $\ \bigcup_{i \in I:\ B_i \in A}\ B_i \subset \tau_q$,since each $\tau_q$ is a topology so it is closed under arbitrarily union of open sets, so $\tau = \bigcup_{i \in I: B_i \in A}\ B_i \subset L$.

Comment: The usual term is base,not basis.And a sub-base is something different. The result is essentially trivial and your proof looks ok but unnecessarily complicated. Also in writing should use complete grammatical sentences and carefully define every term before saying anything about it. The subject is hard enough already,without ESP.

Comment: I accidently wrote sub-base instead of base.

Comment: @user254665 Munkres is pretty well known text that uses basis instead of base.

Comment: I think I also did a little mistake in my notation in the definition of $\tau$ it should be $\{B_i\}$ instead of just union of $B_i$ since $\tau$ is collection of sets not just 1 set is that correct ?